# Can't convert string[] to string

Tags: c#, string, split

Please bear with me, I'm very confused and I may be making completely no sense. I play a game which I have a source to that is coded in c#, and I'm trying to make a command that I use in game, that which plays a sound.

I've got this:

```
string[] Strings = new string[2];
Strings[0] = "sound/1.mp3";
Strings[1] = "1";
SendPacket(General.MyPackets.String(MyChar.UID, 20, Strings));
```

On the Strings in the SendPacket, it says it cannot convert string[] string.

I know I'm doing this wrong, and in an example I've seen someone else do, it contained a "split(' ')", but I'm not sure how to do it.

Here is that example I saw (THIS IS NOT MY CODE, BUT A REFERENCE I TRIED TO USE AND FAILED)

```
{
    string[] Strings = new string[2];
    string[] sound = param.Split(' ');

    Strings[0] = sound[1];
    Strings[1] = "1";
    string todo = sound[0];
    string media = sound[1];

    if (todo == "play")
    {
        CSocket.Send(CoPacket.String(Strings, 0, (Struct.StringType)(20), 2));
    }
    else if (todo == "broadcast")
    {
        foreach (ClientSocket CS in World.ClientPool.Values)
        {
            CSocket.Send(CoPacket.String(Strings, 0, (Struct.StringType)(20), 2));
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

I'm wanting to know how to make my code work, but sending strings(1 and 2). Thanks for any help, and I'm very sorry if I've confused you.

```
public void SendPacket(byte[] Dat)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ListenSock != null)
                if (ListenSock.WinSock.Connected)
                {
                    int Len = Dat[0] + (Dat[1] << 8);
                    if (Dat.Length != Len)
                        return;

                    System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(this, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 8, 0));

                    byte[] Data = new byte[Dat.Length];
                    Dat.CopyTo(Data, 0);

                    Crypto.Encrypt(ref Data);
                    ListenSock.WinSock.Send(Data);

                    System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(this);
                }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

```
public byte[] String(long CharId, byte Type, string name)
    {
        ushort PacketType = 1015;
        byte[] Packet = new byte[13 + name.Length];

        fixed (byte* p = Packet)
        {
            *((ushort*)p) = (ushort)Packet.Length;
            *((ushort*)(p + 2)) = (ushort)PacketType;
            *((uint*)(p + 4)) = (uint)CharId;

            *(p + 8) = Type;
            *(p + 9) = 1;
            *(p + 10) = (byte)name.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
            {
                *(p + 11 + i) = Convert.ToByte(name[i]);
            }
        }

        return Packet;
    }
```

Comment: What is the prototype of `General.MyPackets.String()` function?

Comment: What is signature of SendPacket?

Comment: @mybirthname no it didnt work. im not really sure what is wrong.

Comment: I think you just need to send string[0] to string function, so it should be something like: SendPacket(General.MyPackets.String(MyChar.UID, 20, Strings[0])). If you want to send both the strings then you should first know the proper command separator and then join both the strings using that command separator using String.Join function.

Comment: the seperator was something like split(' ');

Comment: @DeepakBhatia Look at the "Reference" i put in my original post. maybe you'll understand. I'm failing to lol

Comment: Your reference does this: `CSocket.Send(CoPacket.String(Strings, 0, (Struct.StringType)(20), 2));` So why are you doing this: `SendPacket(General.MyPackets.String(MyChar.UID, 20, Strings));` instead?

Comment: @Rob that reference is using a different source than the one I'm using. However the packets are the same, just formatted differently. I'm supposed to send 2 strings, but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: Can you share the code for CoPacket.String function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
string[] Strings = new string[2];
Strings[0] = "sound/1.mp3";
Strings[1] = "1";
SendPacket(General.MyPackets.String(MyChar.UID, 20, String.Join(' ', Strings)));
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'm not sure if we're doing the strings right. Look how the guy did it on the reference. I'm not too savvy with c# so maybe ,and hopefully you can see the solution. Thanks

Comment: he somehow used the Split(' ') and called Strings without even having to convert it to string[]. which is why im confused

Answer (score 0):

**Your error:**

> cannot convert string[] in string

just means that you are trying to convert an array/list of type "string" into a single string, but C# is unable to do this by default so you have to do it yourself.

**Now to your code example**:

He is using a different method from you. He used `String(string[] ?? , ??, ??, ??)` and you `String(long CharId, byte Type, string name)`

This is based on the assumption that his `CoPacket` and your `MyPackets` are the same class.

Comment: What does "do this yourself" mean? How should I do something that C# can't do itself?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string[] Strings = new string[2];
string[] sound = param.Split(' ');

Strings[0] = sound[1];
Strings[1] = "1";
string todo = sound[0];
string media = sound[1];
string concatString = Strings[0] + Strings[1];
if (todo == "play")
{
    CSocket.Send(CoPacket.String(concatString , 0, (Struct.StringType)(20), 2));
}
```